# how to set state in render react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When i want to setState in render lifecycle it gives me this error

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

```
changeInitial(){
   this.setState({initialLoad: false});
}

render() {
    if (this.state.initialLoad) {
        Animated.timing(this.state.listPosition, {
            toValue: 350,
            duration: 2000,
        }).start(() => this.changeInitial());
    }
 }
```

Comment: As the warning says, you should not call `setState()` during a `render()`. You will need to redesign your component in order to avoid doing this.

Comment: The reason of error is that if you setState in render it will trigger a re-render and so on.. You will end up a forever loop.

Comment: You should give more detail what you really need or give us the example... So we might provide you to the right spot. Everything is possible... :D

Comment: you should write your if inside the `componentDidMount()` method

Comment: setState in render it will trigger a re-render.. you will end up a infinity loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `setState()` inside the `render()` method because it triggers a re-render inside the render, throwing an error. The better way to do it is inside the `componentDidMount()` method, like this:

```
changeInitial(){
   this.setState({initialLoad: false});
}
componentDidMount(){
    if (this.state.initialLoad) {
       Animated.timing(this.state.listPosition, {
           toValue: 350,
           duration: 2000,
       }).start(() => this.changeInitial());
    }
}
render() {
    // Your component template here
}
```